# Issue to INSERT value in table when no value (NULL) is selected from dropdownlist (WebMatrix / Razor syntax))

Tags: razor, webmatrix, html-select

If no value is selected from a dropdown list, the UPDATE SQL command will throw me an error of type `Update Statement Conflicts with Foreign Key Constraint`. This is normal since no known value has been selected.

How can this be handled ?

**My code to populate the dropdown list**:

```
var titlesData = db.Query("SELECT TitleId, Name FROM Titles ORDER BY Name");
titlesListItems = titlesData.Select(i => new SelectListItem {
Value = i.TitleId.ToString(),
Text = i.Name,
Selected = i.TitleId == providerData.TitleId ? true : false
});
```

**My code to display the list:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("titlesCombo","-- Please select --",titlesListItems)
```

**My SQL statement**

```
@"INSERT INTO Providers
  (Ref, ProviderTypeId, CompanyName, CompanyTypeId, TitleId, FirstName, LastName)
  VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6)";
  db.Execute(updateCommand, refer, providerTypeId, companyName, companyTypeId, titleId, firstName, lastName)
```

`If one of the "id" fields are null, the insert will fail.
How do I exclude the INSERT of those fields when they have a null value ?`

I thought about forcing a **'dummy' ID value** in the table ('0' for example) through an IF statement and set the 'Selected' to false if that value was found BUT it is not possible since Primary Key in each joined table cannot be set to '0' (or any other value) manually (auto-increment).

What is then the solution ?

Test each (I have many) dropdown list box to exclude the ones where no value has been selected and construct a variable SQL statement ? That look tricky and complicated !

Answer (score 1):

Either make the ID field in the database nullable, or the posted back ID field should be marked with [Required] so validation triggers when no option is selected.

Comment: The ID is nullable as foreign key in one table but not nullable as primary key in the other table ! What do you mean by "the posted back field should be marked with ..." ?

Comment: Is there no way to just "skip" the insert of a specific field if he is found to be null ?

Comment: an if statement around the insert?

Comment: i'm not that familar with webmatrix, but i assumed that you're basically using MVC from the look of the code.  If you're not then ignore my [Required] remark.

Comment: Yes, thought about the IF statement but there are multiples nullable "ID" fields and we have also the problem of the placeholders that need to be decreased ... I'm thinking about creating a function that will construct my SQL statement ... Using Razor syntax in WebMatrix (web pages, not MVC)

Comment: i guess that's where my knowledge comes to its end, i'd need to see the full code for the page to be of any help.